# How do I set HotKeys in Realm Of The Mad God?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

How can I set Hotkeys for Nexus or Potion to use the multiple mouse triggers? I have looked throughout the settings options, and I have not yet found a way.

Answer (score 1):

Some keys cannot be used for hotkeys in Realm of the Mad God. To use these, you will have to use a program such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to make it so whenever you press the trigger on the mouse, it sends the key you have set as the nexus/potion hotkey. For example, to make it so right-click takes you to the nexus, the script would look like this (with the default hotkey of <kbd>r</kbd> for nexus:

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#IfWinActive Realm of the Mad God
RButton::Send r
#IfWinActive
```